# Express Router Prefix

Tags: node.js, express

I am confused about how to properly set up API routing in my express app. What I would like to have is structured way to define routes without repeating myself. As a database I am using RethinkDB. For each model, let's say `Exercise` I have created a file in the `models` directory. These files only define the model / schema. I thought that each model also defines an endpoint for my API. Thus, I have created a `routes` folder in which I declare my routes in separate files, e.g. `exercises.js`. This is my directory structure:

```
root
├── app.js
├── bootstrap.js
├── routes
│   ├── exercises.js
│   ├── index.js
│   └── ...
├── models
│   ├── exercise.js
│   └── ...
└── ...
```

An example route file looks like this:

```
module.exports = (function() {
    'use strict';

    var router = express.Router();

    router.get('/exercises', getAllExercises);
    router.get('/exercises/:id', getExerciseById);

    return router;
})();
```

As you can see I am repeating the route prefix `exercises`. This is a sub-prefix because all routes should start with `/api`. Is it possible to define in a prefix for a single router, so that I use `app.use('/api', [routers])` in the `app.js` and tell each router to have a different route prefix such as `/api/excursions/`? I am confused about my declaration and also ask for feedback. I think there is a better way to organize my API because with what I am doing right know I would also need to include all routes in the `app.js` to pass in all routes to the app as an array. This is my `app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// API Routes
var exercises = require(__dirname + '/routes/exercises');

app.use('/api', [exercises]);

// Start the server
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port '+ port);
```

The array syntax was taken from the offical express [documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write your route files like so:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    'use strict';

    var router = express.Router();

    router.get('/', getAllExercises);
    router.get('/:id', getExerciseById);

    app.use('/api/exercises', router);
};
```

And require each of them like this:

```
require('./routes/exercises')(app);
```

Note that you can replace `__dirname + '/...` with `'./...`.